# Change orientation of UIWebkit based app programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ios4

I have a UIWebkit based app. I want to change the orientation of the webkit when user clicks on a button. I am fine with reloading the html inside the webkit after changing the orientation.

Please help.

Comment: Why change on a button click?  Why not when the user rotates the device?

Comment: Not something that I can control. Its something I have to add somehow.

Comment: Do you have access to the objective-c code or are you restrained through the html?

Comment: If the button is a link you can intercept it the webview delegate then force a rotation transform on the screen. Seems a little odd though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, changing the status bar orientation will rotate the window to match the orientation defined for the status bar, even if the bar is hidden. This worked when I first tried it in iOS 4, but I have not tried it in iOS 5 at all.

Here's the command that does this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) animated:(BOOL)];
```

Comment: That partially helped. Thanks.